# Deserialize Json Array Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, json.net

I have the following JSON

```
[
 {
  "id":"656332",
  "t":"INTU",
  "e":"NASDAQ",
  "l":"108.35",
  "l_fix":"108.35",
  "l_cur":"108.35",
  "s":"2",
  "ltt":"4:00PM EST",
  "lt":"Nov 8, 4:00PM EST",
  "lt_dts":"2016-11-08T16:00:01Z",
  "c":"+0.45",
  "c_fix":"0.45",
  "cp":"0.42",
  "cp_fix":"0.42",
  "ccol":"chg",
  "pcls_fix":"107.9",
  "el":"108.43",
  "el_fix":"108.43",
  "el_cur":"108.43",
  "elt":"Nov 8, 4:15PM EST",
  "ec":"+0.08",
  "ec_fix":"0.08",
  "ecp":"0.08",
  "ecp_fix":"0.08",
  "eccol":"chg",
  "div":"0.34",
  "yld":"1.26"
},
{
  "id":"13756934",
  "t":".IXIC",
  "e":"INDEXNASDAQ",
  "l":"5,193.49",
  "l_fix":"5193.49",
  "l_cur":"5,193.49",
  "s":"0",
  "ltt":"4:16PM EST",
  "lt":"Nov 8, 4:16PM EST",
  "lt_dts":"2016-11-08T16:16:29Z",
  "c":"+27.32",
  "c_fix":"27.32",
  "cp":"0.53",
  "cp_fix":"0.53",
  "ccol":"chg",
  "pcls_fix":"5166.1729"
 }
]
```

I'm trying to deserialize this array and use but I keep getting the following error:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'StockTicker.home+Class1' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Here is my class:

```
 public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string t { get; set; }
        public string e { get; set; }
        public string l { get; set; }
        public string l_fix { get; set; }
        public string l_cur { get; set; }
        public string s { get; set; }
        public string ltt { get; set; }
        public string lt { get; set; }
        public DateTime lt_dts { get; set; }
        public string c { get; set; }
        public string c_fix { get; set; }
        public string cp { get; set; }
        public string cp_fix { get; set; }
        public string ccol { get; set; }
        public string pcls_fix { get; set; }
        public string el { get; set; }
        public string el_fix { get; set; }
        public string el_cur { get; set; }
        public string elt { get; set; }
        public string ec { get; set; }
        public string ec_fix { get; set; }
        public string ecp { get; set; }
        public string ecp_fix { get; set; }
        public string eccol { get; set; }
        public string div { get; set; }
        public string yld { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
var jsonObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

var blah = jsonObject1.Property1[0].c;
```

I have no idea what to do at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception states, your outermost [JSON](http://www.json.org/) container is an array -- a comma-delimited sequence of values surrounded by `[` and `]`.  As such, it needs to be deserialized into a collection of some sort, as is explained in the [docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Lists).  Thus you want to do:

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1 []>(json);
var blah = items[0].c;
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ar9MiC).

Comment: Thank you for the example and explanation... makes total sense.